# Pre calculated counts relative to variety of options

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mongodb, meteor, database

Struggled with the title of this post for the same reason i've struggled to find a solution via google, what am I asking??

I would normally write this app in rails+postgresql but am tempted by meteor+mongodb, although this may not concern the question.

I'm trying to pre calculate and index values for a database model which should change/update depending on other parameters given by a user. The database will contain millions of records so pre populating the values would be ideal.

I will eventually have a database full of 'companies' which have various attributes, such as:

```
location_country
location_city
incorporation_month
incorporation_year
...
```

When listing all companies, the site will allow a user to narrow down listings through the above attributes.

So to start with I would usually add a counter to the value of each attribute when a company is added to the database and have fast access to this count in the listings webpage, something like:

```
select country:
    > England (22 companies)
    > France (26 companies)
    ...
```

But when a person can add multiple parameters to the search things become more tricky:

```
Select incorporation year:
    2015 (126 companies) SELECTED
    2014 (435 companies)
    2013 (315 companies)

# below counts are including the above selection as a parameter
# but should be pre calculated

Select location:
    England (13 companies)
    France (8 companies)
```

I'm trying to figure out what I should be saving to allow me to have a count already in place no matter what sequence of search parameters are given.

The question is very vague because I'm just looking for an indication of what/where I should be possibly searching or reading.

If any could point me in the right direction I would really appreciate it?

Comment: You know what people say about early optimization... You're going to suffer from a combinatorial explosion just keeping all the counts and then updating them all as they change. This question should in no way be the gating item for which framework/stack you choose, this kind of feature has been built in every framework.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option ... keep an array of ID's for the objects that were used to calculated the count, then when you have multiple parameters selected you can do a union of the arrays to get your count.

Example

```
# Anywhere
Counts = new Mongo.Collection("counts");

# Client (or maybe Server method)
countByLocationEngland = Counts.findOne({location_country: 'GB'});

countByIncorporationYear = Counts.findOne({incorporation_year: 2015});

union = _.union(countByLocationEngland.array, countByIncorporationYear.array);

count = union.length
```